# Расположение обводки (stroke) у SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, spritekit

Возможно как нибудь сделать stroke у SKShapeNode с внутренней стороны? По умолчанию она по центру линии обводиться, например если обводка 6 пикселей, то 3 пикселя будут с одной стороны 3 пикселя с другой, а надо что бы все 6 были с внутренней стороны.

Comment: сделать всю shape на 3 пикселя меньше

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko shape используеться с заливкой цвета, так что это не совсем то что надо. Но я так понял что способа нет, и проще создать копию shape без фона, уменьшить его, добавить обводку и наложить поверх shape с фоном.

Comment: либо создать другой shape используя bezierpath